# Getting specific data after button click - Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a donation application that allows donors to donate stuff. I have a screen, called available `supplies.html` which renders out all of the donations from the database using a `for` loop.

Each donation is displayed in a user-friendly way, and contains a button that allows them to see details about that specific donation. When the button is clicked, the user is redirected to a page, which I want to contain details about the donation that they clicked on

My problem is that I can't figure out how to display a specific donation from my model, for example if my user clicked on an *apple* donation, I want to get the details for this donation and display it on another page

**My model:**

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  quantity  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

The unfinished view: (Instead of displaying all of the donations, I want to get the specific details for the donation clicked on in the previous page)

```
def acceptdonation(request):
    donations = Donation.objects.all()
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'acceptdonation.html', context)
```

**EDIT:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/donations/59/

Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'home']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /donations/59/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a `urlpattern` is needed:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('donations/<int:pk>/', views.DonationDetail.as_view(), name='donation-detail')
]
```

Then, you need to process with a view function:

```py
# views.py
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Donation

class DonationDetail(DetailView):
    model = Donation
    queryset = Donation.objects.all()
    template_name = 'donation/detail.html' # whatever template name you want
```

All you need now is to add a link inside your template for the `DonationDetail` view(assuming you already have the list of donations inside your list template as `donations`).

Something along the lines should do the job

```
{% for donation in donations %}
    <a href="{% url 'donation-detail' donation.pk %}"> View Detail </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am trying the code right now. I am wondering as to why you named the view DonationDetail, can I just include the code in my acceptdonation view or do I need to create a new view?

Comment: you can give the `view` any name that you may want, just update the corresponding `urlpattern` accordingly.

Comment: ok, I am also getting the error saying that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.views.generics'

Comment: in my views.py file

Comment: as of now, you're using a function based `view` where you may have to do a lot of boiler-plate stuff yourself. You can use the one I suggested, `django` does more of it for you. See the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: yes it should have been `from django.views.generic import DetailView`. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: I used your code, but I am getting an error saying TypeError at /donations/59/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: please post the complete traceback

Comment: I have added the traceback, hope we get this problem resolved soon. Thank you for your help

Comment: i am not sure you have posted the complete traceback.

Comment: does adding an field `template_name` to whatever template you use for the detail view work?

Comment: I don't have a template_name or anything, i'm not exactly sure what you are talking about

Comment: If I click on the view button that you gave me, I get the error I posted. It is the complete traceback

Comment: Just wondering, you gave me a class to put in my views, should't that be a function? Could this be causing the error

Comment: i have updated the urlpattern to include the `as_view` method. Check if your issue gets resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got the code to work